# Send a slider variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, slider

I have a slider on my html page and I need to pass the input variable (I mean the percentage of slider, so the id) on a php variable in the same page.
I've tried many methods, but no one has worked.

I attach my code below. I don't write here the style tag: ask me for it if you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <input type="range" id="my-slider" min="0" max="100" value="50" oninput="slider()">
            <div id="slider-value">0</div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const mySlider = document.getElementById("my-slider");
            const sliderValue = document.getElementById("slider-value");
            function slider(){
                valPercent = (mySlider.value / mySlider.max)*100;
                mySlider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #3264fe ${valPercent}%, #9c9c9c ${valPercent}%)`;
                sliderValue.textContent = mySlider.value;
            }
            slider();
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give the input tag a name attribute like `<input name="slider" type="range" id="my-slider" min="0" max="100" value="50" oninput="slider()">` and use a form.

Comment: Use a `<form>` or AJAX to send data from the client to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way to do it is to use HTTP GET or POST requests

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="get.php" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
            <input type="range" id="my-slider" name="svalue" min="0" max="100" value="50" oninput="slider()">
            <div id="slider-value">0</div>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const mySlider = document.getElementById("my-slider");
            const sliderValue = document.getElementById("slider-value");
            function slider(){
                valPercent = (mySlider.value / mySlider.max)*100;
                mySlider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #3264fe ${valPercent}%, #9c9c9c ${valPercent}%)`;
                sliderValue.textContent = mySlider.value;
                //document.cookie=`sliderValue=${sliderValue.innerText}; expires=Never; path=\\`;
            }
            slider();


</script>

        </body>
</html>
```

get.php file

```
<?php
$myvar=$_POST["svalue"];
echo "Slide value is: " . $myvar;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing it is to set cookie and get it in PHP
after changing the slide value reload it and you will see PHP echoing the result

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <input type="range" id="my-slider" min="0" max="100" value="50" oninput="slider()">
                <div id="slider-value">0</div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                const mySlider = document.getElementById("my-slider");
                const sliderValue = document.getElementById("slider-value");
                function slider(){
                    valPercent = (mySlider.value / mySlider.max)*100;
                    mySlider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #3264fe ${valPercent}%, #9c9c9c ${valPercent}%)`;
                    sliderValue.textContent = mySlider.value;
                    document.cookie=`sliderValue=${sliderValue.innerText}; expires=Never; path=\\`;
                }
                slider();
    
    
    </script>
    <?php
    $svalue=$_COOKIE["sliderValue"];
    echo $svalue;
    ?>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, you helped me with my project!